# Asp.net c# DDD - problema ao passar dados da Entidade para ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto ASP.NET MVC, com estrutura DDD e utilizando Simple Injector. 
Consigo realizar a persistencia no BD normalmente, porem, no momento de recuperar as informacoes e exibir em uma lista, apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro.

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Domain.Entities.SistemaEntities]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[View.Models.SistemaViewModel]'.

Esse e o controle que esta chamando o metodo para buscas as informacoes:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var resultado = _SistemaDominio.GetAll().AsEnumerable();
            return View(resultado);                 
        }
```

E essa e a pagina que apresenta a lista.

```
@model IEnumerable<View.Models.SistemaViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Insert")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodSistema)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DTCadastro)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodSistema)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DTCadastro)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Update", new { id=item.IDSistema }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.IDSistema }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.IDSistema })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Classe Domain.Service

```
public IList<SistemaEntities> GetAll()
{
    var resultado = _repositorioSistema.GetAll();
    return resultado;
}
```

Classe Data.Repositories

```
public IList<TEntities> GetAll()
{
     return _context.Set<TEntities>().ToList();
}
```

Nao estou conseguindo de forma alguma passar os dados da Entidade para a ViewModel.

Comment: _SistemaDominio.GetAll() deve estar retornando uma Lista de `Domain.Entities.SistemaEntities` e na sua `View` está sendo criado a partir de um a Lista de `View.Models.SistemaViewModel` e o erro é porque os tipos são de classes diferentes.

Comment: Sim, se eu passo os dados da Entidade diretamente para a Presentation, funciona perfeitamente. Porem terei problemas mais pra frente com outros metodos que pretendo aplicar. Eu preciso que os dados sejam passados da Entidade para a ViewModel. E o que nao estou consigo fazer.

Comment: o que tem dentro de `_SistemaDominio.GetAll()`? coloque o código@

Comment: Atualizei com os codigos do _SistemaDominio.GetAll(). 
Ele chama a classe da camada de Dominio que recebe os dados do banco vindo da Data.

Comment: olha Douglas se pode dar um `Select` ali e dar um new nessa `ViewModel` ou pode utilizar pacotes para passar de uma classe para outra como por exemplo AutoMapper. na minha visão é simples e não precisa de pacote.

Comment: Virgilio, muito obrigado pelo help! Deu certo com o AutoMapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o mapeamento do model para o viewModel.
existem algumas bibliotecas para isso, dentre elas o AutoMapper, que pode ser baixado via NuGet.

Após fazer o Download você adiciona uma classe no App_Start, conforme abaixo:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void Configurar()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainProfile());
            config.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

Após isso crie as classes DomainToViewModelProfile e ViewModelToDomainProfile, normalmente eu crio uma pasta "AutoMapper" no projeto MVC e coloca essas duas classes dentro.
Nela você adicionará os mapeamentos, na classe ViewModelToDomainProfile ficarão os mapeamentos que passarão o viewModel para um model(insert e update) e na outra classe, model para viewModel(selects)

```
public class DomainToViewModelProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SistemaEntities, SistemaViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ViewModelToDomainProfile : Profile
{
    public ViewModelToDomainProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SistemaViewModel, SistemaEntities>();
    }
}
```

Após isso, no Global.asax basta chamar a configuração

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AutoMapperConfig.Configurar(); //Chamando configuração AutoMapper
    }
```

Por fim, toda vez que for passar de um model para um viewModel ou de um viewModel para um model você precisará chamar o mapeamento, que no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SistemaEntities> resultado = _SistemaDominio.GetAll();
        List<SistemaViewModel> viewModels = Mapper.Map<List<SistemaViewModel>>(resultado);
        return View(viewModels);                 
    }
```

Ao criar os mapeamentos(CreateMap) eles servirão tanto para collections quando objetos simples.

Comment: MUITO obrigado!!!
Fiz aqui e deu certo com o AutoMapper.