# Error mapping types. Mapping types: ICollection`1 -> List`1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, lista, collection

Estou tendo um problema para converter uma `List` para `ViewModel`, utilizando o `ToListViewModel`.

**FaturaController.cs**

```
FaturaViewModel faturaViewModel = new FaturaViewModel();

faturaViewModel.mensagens = new List<MensagemViewModel>();

faturaViewModel.mensagens = this.ToListViewModel<Mensagem, MensagemViewModel>(_MensagemApplicationService.GetAllAsNoTracking().ToList());

return View(faturaViewModel);
```

O `Model` e a `ViewModel` tem os mesmos campos.

*FaturaViewModel.cs*

```
public List<MensagemViewModel> mensagens { get; set; }
```

**Exception**

```
System.Exception: 'Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
ICollection`1 -> List`1
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Asp.net c# DDD - problema ao passar dados da Entidade para ViewModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230671/asp-net-c-ddd-problema-ao-passar-dados-da-entidade-para-viewmodel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui criando um novo Mapper, tanto do Domanin para ViewModel quando de ViewModel para Domain para a propriedade `public List<MensagemViewModel> mensagens { get; set; }`:

**DomainToViewModel**

```
this.CreateMap<Mensagem, MensagemViewModel>();
```

**ViewModelToDomain**

```
this.CreateMap<MensagemViewModel, Mensagem>();
```

Obs: Também tive que fazer isso para todas as `ViewModels`.