# AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Error mapping types.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Poderiam me ajudar com esse erro descrito no título, por favor.
Estou utilizando o AutoMapper da mesma maneira em outras classes e apenas nessas está dando esse erro. 
Não consegui entender o porque do erro, já que as classes HelpModel e HelpViewModel possuem propriedades iguais. A versão do AutoMapper é 7.0.1.

HelpModel:

```
public class HelpModel
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Area { get; private set; }

    public string Controller { get; private set; }

    public string Action { get; private set; }

    public string Template { get; private set; }




    public HelpModel()
    {
    }
}
```

HelpViewModel:

```
public class HelpViewModel : BaseViewModel
{


    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a {0} referente a Help")]
    [Display(Name = "Área")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Area { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o {0} referente a Help")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Controller { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a {0} referente a Help")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o {0} referente a Help")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Template { get; set; }


    public HelpViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Onde uso o AutoMapper:

```
 public List<HelpViewModel> Listar()
    {
        List<HelpModel> lstHelpModel = _helpRepository.List();

        List<HelpViewModel> lstHelpViewModel = Mapper.Map<List<HelpViewModel>>(lstHelpModel);

        return lstHelpViewModel;
    }
```

Deve ter alguma coisa errada que não consegui perceber.
Valeu.

Comment: Você fez o profile deles? de uma olhada nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230671/asp-net-c-ddd-problema-ao-passar-dados-da-entidade-para-viewmodel/230679#230679, pode ser que algo mude por conta da versão

Comment: Obrigado @Barbetta. Esta resposta me ajudou muito. Com ela entendi melhor as declarações do AutoMapper. No meu caso, temos uma classe MapConfig onde fazemos a a inicialização do map criando os profiles necessários.

Answer (score 2):

Faltava esta declaração na classe de inicialização do Map:

```
config.CreateMap<HelpModel, HelpViewModel>();
```